# Styling WebVTT in Android VideoView

Tags: android, video-streaming, webvtt

I have an HLS stream with WebVTT subtitles and I would like to render the voices with their specific style inside a VideoView. 
In an HTML page I would include the CSS with the ::cue voices styles.
But at the moment I don't see a way to embed the styles definition within WebVTT so I'm wondering if I can define those styles "out-of-band".
What I've found so far is that there's a [WebVttRenderer](http://androidxref.com/5.1.0_r1/xref/frameworks/base/media/java/android/media/WebVttRenderer.java) class in Android but it's not clear if I can pass styles for different voices (that class at the moment is not documented in the Reference Android documentation).
Has anyone ever managed to render natively WebVTT with styles in Android ?